# Resizing an Image with Laravel Image Intervention won't let me save

Tags: laravel, image, resize, intervention

I am having the hardest time resizing an image with Laravel Image Intervention. I am able to name and save images normally, but when I add image intervention it won't save the new file created to the folder.

Here is what I have in my controller

```
 //This all works
        $title = str_slug(request('title'));
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore= $title.'.'.$extension;
        $thumbnailpic= 'thumb'.'-'.$fileNameToStore;
//store image
        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);

//Here is where I am trying to resize and it breaks

        $file = Input::file('cover_image');
        Image::make( $file->getRealPath() )->fit(340, 340)->save('public/cover_images/' . $thumbnailpic);
```

This is the error I get

```
"Can't write image data to path (public/cover_images/thumb-imagename.png)"
```

If I remove the two lines of resize code everything works perfectly. I am running this locally and have made everything open completely for permissions. Not sure what else to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Does the directory `cover_images` exist?

Comment: it does. Laravel itself has no trouble creating the folder and saving there, it seems like image intervention is having the issue

Comment: `->save('public/cover_images/' . $thumbnailpic)`, for Intervention I believe this path starts in the Linux root.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems related save path, Can you try give full path like this,

```
$targetPath = storage_path().'/app/public/cover_images/';
...
->save($targetPath . $thumbnailpic);
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Sadly even with this, I am still getting the error "Can't write image data to path (public/cover_images/thumb-imagename.png)"

Comment: Are you sure your `$file->getRealPath()` returning image ? Because `make` need to get real image path as param.

Comment: How would I tell if $file->getRealPath() is returning an image?

Comment: You can use `dd` for this,

`dd($file->getRealPath())`
So, you can check command output on browser.

Comment: when I use that I get "/private/var/tmp/phphqoRVm"   I'm guessing that isn't right?

Comment: yes, You should use saved image for this, like this,

`Image::make( storage_path().'/app/public/cover_images/'.$fileNameToStore)->fit(340, 340)->save('public/cover_images/' . $thumbnailpic);`

Comment: I tried that but I still get the error "Can't write image data to path (public/cover_images/thumb-imagename.png)" I just dont understand what is happening, I right clicked on that folder and gave it read and write for everyone

Comment: Can you try to save like this, `->save(storage_path().'/app/public/cover_images/' . $thumbnailpic)`

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out. I was saving to the public_path which image intervention obviously didn't like. So I used the code below

```
    $source = storage_path().'/app/public/cover_images/'.$fileNameToStore;
    $target = storage_path().'/app/public/cover_images/' . $thumbnailpic;


    Image::make($source)->fit(140, 140)->save($target);
```

and it worked!